# Marketing Cloud: Current number of used super messages

Tags: marketing-cloud

**Scenario**

In our contract a specific number of super messages is included. We want to monitor the number of super messages that have been used. Is there any way to do it?

**Question**

How can I find out the number of Super Messages I already used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am a bit late to the party but wanted to provide some information on a report that an AE can access in Org62:

Have them go to Entitlements, select Super Messages, and then click “Entitlement Schedules” to bring it up. They’ll probably have to click to view as many records as they can in order to get all the way to the beginning of the term.  In that screen they click "Printable View,” and then once within the print functionality they can save as a PDF. See below. Most AEs have no idea this even exists.

Hope this helps!

[image]

Comment: Account Executives can now share this report via Quip, so you get an overview that is even updated daily.

Answer (score 1):

Strangely enough, there is no ability to easily review Super Message usage across all products (emails, SMS messages, CloudPage impressions, etc). However, you can view email usage across all Business Units by following the steps below on the parent Business Unit:

1. Open the Email app
2. Select **Admin** from the top menu
3. Click on **Subscription Details**
4. Click on **Access Email Send Report**

Comment: How do you configure the reports, so the super messages are shown? I tried out the report and sent a mail using priority "High" which consumes 4 super messages, but the used message count in the report only increased by 1. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: does this include page views?

Comment: As per my answer, you can't report on Super Messages which is rather ridiculous. You should be able to ask your Account Representative to provide a report...

Answer (score 0):

There's no 1 click report to do this, but it is doable. In the reports section, you can export all SMS, Push and Email message summary report. Then compute the super message equivalent. It will be tricky for the email part, but if you know which emails you set as High priority, it should not be a big issue.